# Java: Write HashMap into File

Tags: java, file, save

I'm working on a program that saves two words into a HashMap. I need to be able to take the HashMap key and value and write it into a file as "key:value" format. When my save() method is called, the HashMap contents are supposed to be written into the file whose name was given as parameter to the constructor. The method returns false if the file can't be saved; otherwise it returns true. However, its not working if the File does not exist.  It's also not saving changes made to an existing file.  I'm not understanding how to read/write files too well... Thank you.

```
package dictionary;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class MindfulDictionary {

private HashMap<String, String> words;
private File file;

public MindfulDictionary() {
    this.words = new HashMap<String, String>();
}

public MindfulDictionary(String file) {
    this.file = new File(file);
    this.words = new HashMap<String, String>();
}

public boolean load() {
    try {
        Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(this.file);
        while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = fileReader.nextLine();
            String[] parts = line.split(":");   // the line is split at :

            String word = parts[0];
            String trans = parts[1];
            this.add(word, trans);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("nope");
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean save() {
    boolean saved = true;
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(this.file.getName(), true));
        for (String key : this.words.keySet()) {
            writer.write(key + ":" + this.words.get(key) + "\n");
            writer.newLine();
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return saved;
}

public void add(String word, String translation) {
    if ((!this.words.containsKey(word))) {
        this.words.put(word, translation);
    }
}

public String translate(String word) {
    if (this.words.containsKey(word)) {
        return this.words.get(word);
    } else if (this.words.containsValue(word)) {
        for (String key : this.words.keySet()) {
            if (this.words.get(key).equals(word)) {
                return key;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public void remove(String word) {
    if (this.words.containsKey(word)) {
        this.words.remove(word);
    } else if (this.words.containsValue(word)) {
        String remove = "";
        for (String key : this.words.keySet()) {
            if (this.words.get(key).equals(word)) {
                remove += key;
            }
        }
        this.words.remove(remove);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: In `save()`, don't silently ignore the `Exception`.  Put `e.printStackTrace()` in the `catch` block and see if any exceptions are raised.

Comment: Also, don't call `writer.close()` within the for loop.  Put it after the closing brace of the for loop. (Or, better still, look into [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) blocks).

Comment: If you are "not understanding how to read/write files too well" put this program aside and write some much simpler programs that just write strings to files and read them. Get that sorted out without the HashMap.

Answer (score 3):

Notice this part of your code,

```
try {
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(this.file.getName(), true));
    for (String key : this.words.keySet()) {
        writer.write(key + ":" + this.words.get(key) + "\n");
        writer.newLine();
        writer.flush();
        writer.close(); // !!
    }
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

Here, you are calling `close()` on the `BufferedWriter` object. You can  not use the object after you have called `close()` on it.

> Once the stream has been closed, further write() or flush() invocations will cause an IOException to be thrown.

Read more about `close()` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close--).

Also, since you are catching all the exceptions and not doing anything with them, you did not notice the `IOException` . In future NEVER do this. At the least log any exception that occurs. This will help you with your debugging.